# Parent selector problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Hi all I have the jq code like this:

Adding element:

```
  $(".wynink_main").live("mouseenter", function() {
  $(this).append("<div class='mapa_dojazdu'>Mapa dojazdu</div>");
  });
```

In div .wynik_main are some divs with text.
And now when I click on div .mapa_dojazdu, I would like to get text from span .miejsce, which is append to div .wynik_main but it doesn't work.

Here is my wrong code:

```
$(".mapa_dojazdu").live("click", function () {
  var is =  $(this).closest("div").find(".miejsce").html();
  alert(is);
});
```

Comment: please paste ur html code too. or create a fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Change

`var is =  $(this).closest("div").find(".miejsce").html();`

to:

`var is = $(this).parent().closest("div").find(".miejsce").html();`

and it should work fine. See example working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/ggEa6/1/). The problem is that `closest()` starts with the current element, and as the current element is a `div`, it stops right there.

Comment: I've just tested it, and it works in IE7, 8 and 9... What version are you using?

Comment: IE 9, where in debuger I can switch on IE 7 and 8

Comment: Have you tried the fiddle I gave a link to? Is that giving `null` as well? I think you must be doing something wrong elsewhere, because that fiddle works for me in IE7, 8, 9, Firefox 4 and Chrome 12. And I'm almost 100% sure it would work in the vast majority of modern browsers.

Comment: check this: www.baza-firm.imap24.pl , site. Click on Katalog Branż next on one letter f.e. A, and then f.e. Administracja obiektów użyteczności publicznej (154). When results will loaded You will see some divs. When mouse will be over on one of the div "Mapa dojazdu" will appear then click it. Check result on Chrome ond IE. You will see.

Comment: I can't be sure, and no offence but I don't want to spend hours trawling through your code, but I have a feeling it's something to do with the fact that your page forces IE into quirks mode. Fix your markup, and I'm sure it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`$(this).closest("div").find(".miejsce").html()`

to

`$(this).closest(".wynink_main").find(".miejsce").html()`.

`div` is too general and will target other divs.

http://jsfiddle.net/ULjKC/